# How to convert the data in proper format for Kmean or any other clustering algorithem

Tags: arrays, pyspark, k-means

I have a big data set with tewmp curves that I would like to cluster them. the data looks like:

| id | temp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [[22.0,116.0,31.0,87.0],[582.0,115.0,31.0,87.0],[1544.0,115.0,31.0,86.0],[2558.0,114.0,31.0,86.0]] |
| 2 | [[68.0,135.0,29.0,65.0], [374.0,128.0,29.0,65.0], [1338.0,127.0,29.0,65.0], [1845.0,127.0,29.0,64.0], [2353.0,126.0,29.0,64.0], [2859.0,126.0,29.0,63.0], [3873.0,126.0,29.0,62.0], [4844.0,126.0,29.0,61.0], [6365.0,125.0,29.0,61.0], [6872.0,125.0,29.0,60.0]] |
| ... | .... |

The data has the schema
id -- long,
temp -- string

Each of the lists on the temp column is a data point that means:

| Milisekonds | pot temp | Ambient temp | object temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22.0 | 116.0 | 31.0 | 87.0 |

For this reason I would like to convert them as it is in a proper format for KMean algorithem.

I was trying to convert the data as array but the elemt are still string. After that I was also exploding the data on many columns and concatinate them again with Vector assambler and then group by id/ collect list also the format was not proper for.
May be somone can help me how to preprocess the data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to split the string values in the 'temp' column into lists of numerical values. You can achieve this using Python's built-in string manipulation functions.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

# Assuming you're using PySpark
df = df.withColumn("temp", split(df["temp"], ",\s*").cast(ArrayType(DoubleType())))
```

Explode the List into Multiple Rows: Explode the list of temperature values into multiple rows while retaining the 'id' column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

df = df.select("id", explode("temp").alias("temp_value"))
```

create Individual Columns for Temperature Features: After exploding, you will have a single column 'temp_value' containing the individual temperature values. Create separate columns for each feature (milliseconds, pot temp, ambient temp, object temp).

```
df = df.withColumn("milliseconds", df["temp_value"][0]) \
       .withColumn("pot_temp", df["temp_value"][1]) \
       .withColumn("ambient_temp", df["temp_value"][2]) \
       .withColumn("object_temp", df["temp_value"][3])
```

Drop Unnecessary Columns: You can drop the `'temp_value'` column, as it is no longer needed.

```
df = df.drop("temp_value")
```

Assemble Features into a Vector: To use K-Means, you should assemble these features into a single vector column. You can do this using a Vector Assembler.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

feature_columns = ["milliseconds", "pot_temp", "ambient_temp", "object_temp"]
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=feature_columns, outputCol="features")
df = assembler.transform(df)
```

Cluster Using K-Means: Now you can apply the K-Means clustering algorithm to the 'features' column.

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans(k=your_desired_number_of_clusters, seed=1)
model = kmeans.fit(df)
```

Get Cluster Labels: After fitting the K-Means model, you can get the cluster labels for each data point.

```
df_with_clusters = model.transform(df)
```

Now, your data is preprocessed and clustered using the K-Means algorithm. You can explore and analyze the clusters in 'df_with_clusters' for further insights. Adjust the number of clusters according to your specific use case and data characteristics.